# code for candlestick pattern in trading 3 candles with 3 different conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPdLJ.jpg)

I hello everyone, above given image is from trading. i tried to code for conditions given in image but i am unable to effecienty code for it. so, give it a try to solve this problem it would be helpfull..bellow are code

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried so far. This platform is to correct any code that *you* have written and are facing errors in, not for completely writing out code. If you want someone to code the entire thing, you can hire someone for that.

Comment: how can i share that big code.. is there any other way to shaare code?

Comment: You can use a website like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Don't share big code, make a [mcve]